# yescrypt python

Tags: python

Мне необходимо сравнить введенный пользователем пароль, с паролем, который есть в системе, он захеширован через yescrypt, вида: `$y$j9T$K3u.5TqXAC694pkVe/Wok.$r/j.U6FOcyXatFfJpXqrgVqyxduiaMqWjxv1qBk4CO0`.
Я очень много гуглил разные репозитории и статьи, но не смог ничего толком нарыть, нашел утилиту mkpasswd, которая в терминале сразу сможет генерировать хэш пароля, но его надо скачивать, так что этот вариант не подходит. Сможет ли кто помочь найти скрипт алгоритма либо чтобы захэшировать пароль в yescrypt, либо наоборот ? Я находил разные репозитории, но не смог в них разобраться

Comment: 73 символа, при этом не только 16-ричные. Не похоже это на хэш, везде с виду обычный хэш должен быть https://github.com/namuyan/yescryptR64-python

Comment: Ну это не то, в системе зашифровано именно вот так

Comment: нагуглил, что $y$ значит, что это yescrypt, j9t это параметр, а дальше соль